# Is that a typo in Lang’s book? (The quadratic form)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I’m reading *Calculus of several variables* by Serge Lang, and in the section on Taylor’s formula, i suspect that there is mistake in the equation  [image]

It seems like Lang skipped the line $$h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)+ k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b) $$ which should before this $$\frac{1}{2}(h^2...)$$

Comment: "Assume that $P$ is a critical point for $f$"

Comment: If $P$ is a critical point then $D_1f=D_2f=0$ But this implies $D_1^2f=D_2^2f=0$ So why he didn’t remove this term? @TheSilverDoe

Comment: The fact that $P$ is a critical point implies that $Df(P)=0$, but this does not imply that $D^2f(P)=0$ ! Think about the function $f : x \mapsto x^2$ : it has a critical point at $x=0$ since $f'(0)=0$, but you have $f''(0)=2$ so the second derivative does not vanish at the critical point.

Answer (score 3):

Critical point is a point where the differential isn't full-rank. In the case of a map $\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R$, where $m\ge1$, this means that the differential is the zero map.